# Unregister broadcastreceiver in OnReceive after message has been sent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've been struggling a little for some time about registering/unregistering a broadcastreceiver. A message must be sent if a particular condition has been met and the receiver is registered dynamically.

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    brSendSMS = new BroadcastReceiverSendSMS();

    try {
        PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);

        int length = message.length();


        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(brSendSMS, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if (length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {

        } else {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSend, null);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have to wait for some seconds to get the broadcast result. After the result has been delivered in OnReceive method of receiver, this is also where I put the unregistering.

```
public class BroadcastReceiverSendSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK:
                result = "Message sent.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                result = "Message not sent.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                result = "No service.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                result = "Null PDU.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                result = "Radio off.";
                break;
        }
        context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);

     }
}
```

Does using `this` keyword enough to get through the instance of this receiver and to unregister it? Keeping or removing this line of code does not throw any exception. It is not even showing signs of leaks.

If this is not the proper way, what would be it?

Comment: I think you have to unregisterReceiver brSendSMS. Like unregisterReceiver(brSendSMS);

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your broadcast receiver in sendSMS method. So to uregister that you need to pass the context of that activity in which sendSms is. So at time when you initialize instead of:

```
brSendSMS = new BroadcastReceiverSendSMS();
```

Use:

```
brSendSMS = new BroadcastReceiverSendSMS(getContext());
```

Also create constructor in your BroadcastReceiverSendSMS class in which you set

```
Context context;
this.context = context;
```

For that add this before @Override:

```
Context parentActivityContext;
public BroadcastReceiverSendSMS (Context activityContext)
    {
        this.parentActivityContext = activityContext;
    }
```

Also change this:

```
context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);
```

to:

```
unregisterReceiver(parentActivityContext);
```

Comment: For further assistance do let me know also dont forget to mark post as answer if it works for you. Happy Codding :)

Comment: I update answer implement this and you will be good to go with it :)